# What does scipy.signal.convolve2d calculate?

Tags: python, scipy

I am currently a bit confused by the output of

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scipy.signal

image = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
         [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
         [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
         [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
         [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]

filter_kernel = [[-1, 1, -1],
                 [-2, 3, 1],
                 [2, -6, 0]]

res = scipy.signal.convolve2d(image, filter_kernel,
                              mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
print(res)
```

It was

```
[[  -2   -8   -7   -6   -5   -4   28]
 [   3   -7  -10  -13  -16  -19   14]
 [ -18  -28  -31  -34  -37  -40    0]
 [ -39  -49  -52  -55  -58  -61  -14]
 [ -60  -70  -73  -76  -79  -82  -28]
 [ -81  -91  -94  -97 -100 -103  -42]
 [-101  -61  -63  -65  -67  -69  -57]]
```

I expected the top left element to be `3*1 + 1*2 + (-6) *8 + 0*9 = -43` (ommitting the padded zeros).

I thought this would expand the matrix image \in R^{7x7} to R^{9x9} by adding one 0 to the left / right and top / bottom. Then I thought the `filter_kernel` would be calculated by "sliding" it over the `image`. At each position, the numbers from the image are point-wise multiplied with the numbers from the kernel. The nine products are the summed up and written into `res`.

However, it is `-2`. Obviously, something different happens.

Comment: *"I expected the top left element to be 3*1 + 1*2 + (-6) *8 + 0*9 = -43 (ommitting the padded zeros)."*  You have it backwards.  You must reverse the order of the values in the kernel.

Answer (score 12):

Convolution reverses the direction of one of the functions it works on. Check The [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition): one function is parameterized with τ and the other with -τ. The same applies to 2D convolution.

You need to mirror the kernel to get the expected resut:

```
filter_kernel = [[0, -6, 2],
                 [1, 3, -2],
                 [-1, 1, -1]]

res = scipy.signal.convolve2d(image, filter_kernel,
                              mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
print(res[0, 0])
# -43
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why a kernel is reversed?

Comment: @CoolCoder Good question, not easy to answer. Reversing one of the functions makes the convolution commutative: you get the same result if you swap image and kernel. This often is a desirable property. It also makes sense in the context of filtering signals. If the kernel is an impulse response, reversing the kernel kind of aligns "older" and "newer" portions of signal and kernel...